# setFetchSource() method removed from InnerHitsBuilder.Any other way to disable '_source' field for inner hits?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

While using `InnerHitsBuilder` in java (elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar), I need to set **_source** flag to false for nested inner hits. With the ES jar version I am using, I could not find a way to do that. [**This**](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17291/files)  shows that this provision was there, but got removed later.
 Can someone help me find a way here?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Wasn't aware of this class FetchSourceContext.java 
We can set 'fetchSource' of the above class and pass it into InnerHitBuilder.